# Babel @babel/preset-es2015 Module not found

Tags: vue.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've installed babel 7 through the documentation command.

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

[image]

But I'm getting error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-es2015'
```

I've tried it 4 to 5 times with clean reinstallation but doesn't work, my webpackconfig file is.

```
// BABEL
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", '@babel/preset-es2015']
                },
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            },
```

Not sure why it is not using the @babel/preset-es2015 it is installed in the project node_modules/@babel/preset-es2015 directory.

[image]

Comment: In webpack config file instead of query, did you try with options for e.g.

`{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", '@babel/preset-es2015']
                },
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            },`

Comment: @MSoheb Thank you, just tried it, it doesn't work either, I've also tried it by putting it in .babelrc

Comment: Would you paste the complete webpack config?

Comment: FYI my bable rc configuration:

`{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8", "ie >= 11"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
  ]
}`

Also just delete the node_modules folder and run npm install or yarn

Comment: @MSoheb, here is my complete webconfig https://textbin.net/bzC8u1djRQ I'm trying what you have provided

Comment: @MSoheb Thank you it is compiling but not working in IE 11, as these type of functions not supported in IE 11  https://imgur.com/iFgK4E5

Comment: The problem is @babel/preset-es2015 is not working, it is must for IE 11 compatibility

Comment: I am glad it is working, in your package.json file would try adding `"browserslist": "> 0.25%, not dead"` or in targets in babelrc mention `"ie": "11"`

Comment: @MSoheb Added that line, but that didn't change anything preset-es2015 not working  https://imgur.com/vmvrRHg     https://imgur.com/B9lsEMR

Comment: as of now webpack is not working? you said it's compiling but the screen shot above still show as error module not found

Comment: Sometimes as we have errors from node dependencies too, we are transpiling our code but the node_modules, that could be one of the issues

Comment: @MSoheb actually it only works when we remove @babel/preset-es2015, so IE 11 is missing when we remove it

Comment: I found this [Babel 7 and WebPack](https://www.thebasement.be/working-with-babel-7-and-webpack/), I think if you follow this you will be able to solve the issue of supporting ie 11

Comment: @MSoheb Thank you for your help, actually, there was dependency package which was making the problem

Comment: Glad, its working